[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ea2076c0 (Expo SDK51)
For some reason whenever I try to open a certain type of modal within my Expo SDK 51 app I get keep getting this error. The user flow goes like so, a user tries to connect the app to a website by scanning a QR code, a couple requests are made to validate the QR code, the QR code is validated, then the modal screen is opened (which is a containedTransparentModal from React Navigation) and has a child BottomSheet (made with Gorhom Bottom Sheet).
However, I've noticed that the modal isn't the only thing that causes this app crashing error. I noticed that after attempting to carry out this user flow a few times that the app just ceases to open entirely and throws this error immediately after attempting to download an OTA EAS update.
The only solution was to completely get rid of the flow. But without this flow we will need to get rid of the entire feature.

For some strange reason, this only happens in our beta build, which we use for internal testing
